# Is there an IC that works like a queue for binary, serial data (like a shift register)?

Tags: integrated-circuit, shift-register, data

Is there an IC that works like a queue for binary, serial data?  I have searched a few sites for an IC like this, but I have no idea what the name of this IC would be. Here is a basic description of what I am looking for:

The chip has at least 7 pins,

- VCC
- Ground
- Data in
- Clock in
- Data out
- Clock out
- Latch

This IC would be connected to two other devices, one that sends data and one that receives data.  Data would be "shifted in" (like a 74HC595 shift register) using the 'data in' and 'clock in', filling the input buffer.  Then, activating the latch would copy the data from the inout buffer to the output buffer.  Finally, the output buffer would "shifted out" using the 'data out' and 'clock out' pins (like a 74HC165 shift register.)  This is the basic functionality.  This IC may also have reset pins, serial-out pin on the input side, and serial-in on the output side.  Bonus: 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit and 64 bit versions  (although, a single chips could perform all of these, it it had the right pins.)

I could easily build this by connecting the outputs of a 74HC595 to the inputs of a 74HC165.  I am hopping that this configuration exists on a single IC

Comment: A shift register is FIFO, but a stack is typically LIFO.  Which do you want?

Comment: FIFO, right, sorry about the confusion... I should have said queue

Comment: If you think that an HC595 / HC165 combination would work, then you may not need a FIFO at all, just a pipeline. The difference is that a FIFO can hold an arbitrary amount of data, between empty and full, depending on its size. 16 word fifos were real common in there day, now they are bigger. Here are some: http://www.jameco.com/1/3/fifo-memory-ic

Answer (score 1):

There used to be "FIFO" (First-In, First-Out) chips and probably still available for vintage maintenance.

But these days it is so easy to implement FIFO in a $4, Arduino chip most of those LSI functions have gone extinct.  You may need to use the "Wayback Machine" to find anything here in 2016.

Comment: Arduino is a nice option, but I would like to avoid software and clock cycles and implement the entire thing using hardware.  FIFO looks promising.  The 74F433 look a bit like what I am searching for.

Comment: Some FIFO chips are still produced; check out <http://www.idt.com/products/memory-logic/fifo-products>

Comment: There is also one on amazon, but it is about as expensive as an Arduino: http://www.amazon.com/dp/B001ULW3SK/ref=cm_sw_r_tw_dp_Ew7vxb02KX85Q

Comment: For anything special purpose IC, the cost is just not worth the extra. Instead, use CPLDs, such as Xilinx's XC9572 or XC2C2A.